# Multiple file upload from Angular into ASP.NET Core API, but files are empty

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have this angular code which should upload some model data and 2 files.

```js
    addCodingQuestion(question: CodingQuestion, template: File, json: File): Observable<CodingQuestion> {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Name', question.name);
        formData.append('Text', question.text);
        formData.append('MaxScore', question.maxScore.toString());
        formData.append('files', template);
        formData.append('files', json);
        return this.http.post<CodingQuestion>(`${this.questionsApi}/code`, formData);
      }
```

And api code for receiving those files and model.

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
        [Route("code")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostCodeExercise ([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files, [FromForm] AdminPostExercise exercise)
        {
            try
            {
                if (files.Count < 2)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Too few files when posting new exercise");
                }
                var codeDTO = new AdminPostCodeExercise(exercise.Name, exercise.Text, exercise.MaxScore, files[0], files[1]);

                var created = await _exerciseService.PostCodeExercise(codeDTO);
                if (created is null)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Couldn't create new exercise with given data");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Created($"api/exercise/{created.Id}", created);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }
```

However when posting from the angular function I receive no files, just the model. But when posting from Postman [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw03a.png) everything works fine. What is going wrong here? It seems like the model binding is failing since the files are in the request header when I post from the angular front end, however I have no idea how to fix this. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: How are you doing the file bit here? What code calls this function?

Comment: @MikeOne for Angular? I simply have two file input fields bound. It works fine, I know I have the files by the time I reach the 'addCodingQuestion' function. It's just that the files are not being bound to the web api IFormFile list.

Comment: I would need to see the code to determine if that is working correctly. Something might be wrong there as you state that everything is fine with Postman..

Comment: You should check the request headers that Postman uses, most likely you need to add `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header.